# Can't set border radius on div enclosing video

Tags: css, html, html5-video

So I'm, trying to make a rounded corner video by enclosing the `<video>` tag in a div with rounded corners.  Works great in Chrome & FF but not Safari.  I'm guessing it's just a limitation of Safari but just thought I'd throw it out there and see if someone knows of a workaround.

```css
.container {
  max-width: 560px;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: block;
  border-radius: 6px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

#video {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <video width="100%" autoplay muted id="video">
        <source src="http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        Your browser does not support the video tag.
    </video>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can reproduce this issue in Safari 11.1. I was able to resolve it by applying the `border-radius` directly to the video element like so:

```css
.container {
  max-width: 560px;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: block;
  border-radius: 6px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

#video {
  border-radius: inherit;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <video width="100%" autoplay muted id="video">
        <source src="http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        Your browser does not support the video tag.
    </video>
</div>
```

Comment: Interesting, I had just assumed that the video element itself couldn't be styled.  Thanks!